# Reducer for async action is adding the response into an object with the same key name as the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am creating an async action in Redux with Redux-Thunk and while the action works and returns the data, when it is added to the state it is put inside an object with the same name as the reducer, like so...

[image: duplicate key name]

The posts key should just have the array of items but it is instead an object with a posts key. What could be causing this issue? Here is the code for the async action...

```
export function getApiData() {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => dispatch(
            {
                type: ActionTypes.GET_API_DATA,
                payload: json
            }
        ))
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the reducer...

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ActionTypes.GET_API_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The other keys like user and prizes (which are not async actions) work perfectly fine and the new data is added as expected to them. What is leading to this behavior when it comes to the posts key and the async action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thge error is in how you process the action in `posts` reducer. You need to return the array instead of an object

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ActionTypes.GET_API_DATA:
            return [
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
            ] // or return action.payload if you don't want to merge data
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: If I set it to return an array it gives me a parsing error. If I just return action.payload it does work as expected, however isn't that mutating the state?

Comment: No it isn't mutating the array since you are completely changing the reference and the new array holds the reference of `action.payload` instead of previous state in reducer

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the response is in the correct format? Could you try attach a debugger or a console.log to see the data? Or try send to dispatch the json.data.